# Jpype crashing on Windows Python 2.7 with jpype.startJVM command

Tags: python-2.7, windows-server-2016, jpype

We are trying to connect via JDBC via Python 2.7.14 on Windows Server 2016.

We just installed the latest version of Python and Java.

Typing this code at the Python command line is crashing Python for us:

```
>>> import jpype
>>> jpype.startJVM("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_171\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll")
```

This gives the error: "python.exe has stopped working."

How do we get jpype running?

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for a solution for days. Here are the main alternatives I have tried:

1. Check If Python and Java are the same version (ie. both are 32 bits or 64 bits). It was OK in my case.
2. I've heard of some memory issues and tried the following to free the garbage collector :

   ```
   import gc

   gc.collect()
   ```

It didn' work for me...

3. I've tried to migrate my environment to Anaconda 3.5 and use the jpype-3. Didn't work either
4. I migrated to **JDK11**, edited the JAVA_HOME variable to the JDK11 path, and tried with Anaconda 2.7. **This finally solved the problem for me**.